# Django admin not loading individual app pages

Tags: django, django-admin

I've just set up a new local version of my django application, and all working fine until I checked on the django admin.

`127.0.0.1:8000/admin` works fine and brings up the usual Django Admin homepage with full list of apps, but when I click into any of the individual app elements it breaks. The URL changes, but instead of displaying that app's admin site it shows an oddly rendered version of the admin homepage, with the app list collapsed on left side of screen (see screenshots below)

Can't immediately see which parts of codebase could be relevant here, so please request copies of any code you want to see.

The correctly displayed Django Admin homepage

[image]

How it renders when I click into any of the individual app/model admin sites

[image]

As above, with list of all apps expanded from left

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me when I upgraded to django 3.1.

Set `admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False` on your `admin.py` file.

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

Actually the admin does load the pages for every model but the `nav_sidebar` takes all the space. If you zoom out long enough you'll see the models and forms are there.

Comment: You absolute star! Worked perfectly.